# Prerender dynamic content VueJs app with node and cache the prerendered page for a day

Tags: node.js, caching, vuejs2, prerender

I have a VueJS app with dynamic content pages. I want to implement SEO.

I have tried to use prerender-spa-plugin following "https://coursetro.com/posts/code/140/Vue-Prerender-Plugin-Tutorial---Vue-2-SEO-without-Server-Side-Rendering" tutorial, however, it requires to set all the routes while routes being handled by Vue.

Can someone help me how can I set this up using node middleware and **cache** the prerendered page for a day? Also, I do all the configuration in the vue.config.js file because I do not have any webpack.config file. I need to set up the **Nginx config to prerender pages for bots** and provide a **node app to deliver the prerendered Page** on the fly. I am new to Vue is there any approach for this?